# how to find the largest contour in opencv c++

Tags: c++, opencv, contour

I want to extract the main object in images. So I applied grabcut algorithm for the image. From that I want to take the largest contour in the result image resulted from the grabcut algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

Just use `findContours` function to find all contours with `GC_FGD` value. After this use `contourArea` and simple iteration through all contours to find contour with the biggest square.