# findContours, contourArea give errors with nested contours. "Assertion failed", "input array is not a valid matrix"

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision, contour

I am trying to find the largest contour in a binarized image. Judging by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11838942/how-to-find-the-largest-contour-in-opencv-c) and [this tutorial](http://harismoonamkunnu.blogspot.de/2013/06/opencv-find-biggest-contour-using-c.html) you would think this is trivial, and I agree. When I run my code on [the image below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K1PzV.png) though, it produces errors. Note the 2x2 dot in the upper left hand corner, which should count as one contour.

[image: problem.png]

```
Mat img = imread("problem.png", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
vector<vector<Point>> ContourVector;
findContours(img, ContourVector, CV_RETR_LIST, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);
//findContours(img, ContourVector, CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);    // Alternative mode

int biggest = 0;
double BiggestContourArea = contourArea(ContourVector[biggest]);
for (int i = 1; i != ContourVector.size(); ++i){
if ( (contourArea(ContourVector[i])) > BiggestContourArea) {
    biggest = i;
    BiggestContourArea = contourArea(ContourVector[biggest]);
}
}
img = Scalar(0,0,0);
drawContours(img, ContourVector, biggest, Scalar(255,255,255), CV_FILLED );
imshow("Largest contour", img);
waitKey(0);
```

If mode CV_RETR_LIST is used, I get this error at i = 3, although ContourVector has size 4. Why would the vector be larger than the number of contours, though?

```
"Assertion failed: (0 <= contourIdx && contourIdx < (int)last) in unknown function, file ..[..]contours.cpp, line 1810"
```

If mode CV_RETR_EXTERNAL is used (which would make more sense), I get this error. Why would this happen

```
OpenCV Error: Bad argument (input array is not a valid matrix)  in unknown function, file ..[..]utils.cpp, line 54
```

I'd be grateful if someone could explain those errors.

I also wonder why the result of contourArea inside the loop is 0 for some reason and ContourVector[i].size() gives an absurdly large number (around 4 billion).

Comment: What version of OpenCV are you using? Your code works fine for me. Also, your comparison logic might be clearer using `std::max_element` and a custom comparator, and `std::distance` to find `biggest`. But it works either way.

Comment: Did you try it on the same picture? I've tried all OpenCV versions from 2.4 to 2.6, they all gave the same behaviour. I am using Visual Studio 2012, maybe I should try reinstalling.

Comment: I used the picture you posted on OS X with version 2.4.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to have been a compatibility issue with Visual Studio 2012 and the prebuilt libraries provided by OpenCV. After I installed and used Visual Studio 2010 to run the code, the problems disappeared.

I assume that you could also solve this by building OpenCV from the source code with VS 2012, but I did not manage. There is a manual [here](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_install/windows_install.html), but it is out-of-date (there is no "source" directory in the git).

I had other weird problems with this project in VS 2012 as well which are in line with some library trouble. Compiling the code worked fine in debug and release mode, but executing it gave an error in debug mode. In release mode, it *seemed* to work, but it produced errors such as the one that sparked this question.

For the protocol, I linked "/build/x86/vc10/lib" as the additional library directory in VS 2012, and the errors were produced with OpenCV versions 2.4.4 to 2.4.6.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot judge for the CV_EXTERNAL case. BUt in the first case the problem seems simple.

```
for (int i = 1; i != ContourVector.size(); ++i){
    if ( (contourArea(ContourVector[i])) > BiggestContourArea) {
        biggest = i;
        BiggestContourArea = contourArea(ContourVector[biggest]);
    }
}
```

In C++ arrays and vectors are indexed from zero. So first item in vector has index `0`, and the last one has `ContourVector.size() - 1`.

To fix you code simply change the for cycle to:

```
for (int i = 1; i < ContourVector.size(); ++i)    ....
```

Comment: That would have been cleaner, but that doesn't fix it. The error occurs at index 3, which should exist when the size is 4.

Answer (score 0):

In response to your last post (This seems to have been a compatibility issue...), did you try using "/build/x86/vc11/lib" instead of vc10 for VS 2012? I'm by no means an expert, but that could be a mismatch of libraries. (vc11 is definitely in 2.4.6 openCV, not sure before that)

Don
Have a great day